# Object's parameter is not a member of Object(UNITY EDITOR)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I've got errors

> Assets/TextPierwszy.js(22,28): BCE0019: 'id' is not a member of 'Object'. 
>   Assets/TextPierwszy.js(24,38): BCE0019: 'id' is not a member of 'Object'.

when trying to compile that script in UnityScript.

```js
#pragma strict
private var pole : UI.Text;
public var Started = false;

public var Ludnosc = new Array();

public class Human {
    public var id : byte;
    public var gender : byte; // 0=k 1=m
    public var age : byte;
    public var pregnant : byte;
    function Breed(partner) {
        // Tu będzie logika rozmnażania
    }
    public var parents : int[]; //Najpierw podajemy ID matki, potem ID ojca.
}

function Test1() {
    if(!Started) {
        Started = true;
        Ludnosc.push(new Human());
        Ludnosc[0].id = 1; //Line number 22
        Debug.Log(Ludnosc.length);
        Debug.Log(Ludnosc[0].id); //Line number 24
        }
}
```

How can I tell compiler to track Ludnosc[0] as instance of Human instead of tracking it at plain Object?
Or is there problem in other place? Also tried
`public var Ludnosc : Human = new Array();`
but this don't work too. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when you initialize `Ludnosc` using:

```js
public var Ludnosc = new Array();
```

you're creating an array of `Object` elements. As a result, when you try to access `Ludnosc[0].id`, `Ludnosc[0]` is treated an an `Object` and hence does not have `id` available to it.

To address this, either initialize `Ludnosc` as a built-in array like so:

```js
public var Ludnosc : Human[];

Ludnosc = new Human[1]; // When you're initializing it
Ludnosc[0] = new Human(); // When you're populating it
```

Or, if you really want to use a JavaScript array, you can cast the `Object` to a `Human` when you access the value in `Test1()`, modify the typecasted version, then place it back into the array (haven't tested this code):

```js
function Test1() {
    if(!Started) {
        Started = true;
        Ludnosc.push(new Human());
        var tempHuman = Ludnosc[0] as Human;
        tempHuman.id = 1;
        Ludnosc[0] = tempHuman; // Overwriting with the updated Human
        Debug.Log(Ludnosc.length);
        Debug.Log(tempHuman.id);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you very much! Second solution works fine, because I want _unlimited_ array which I don't need to re-initialize when I want to get more "space" for more humans.

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help out.